Heart Alone as example of Phrygian mode, what key should be reflected in transcription?
The very popular Heart 80s balad Alone changes between Bb Phrygian (chorus, parts of guitar lead) and Bb minor (verses). Bb Phrygian can be represented by Gb major key signature (6 flats), while Bb minor has 5. Transcriptions I have seen typically peg the song as being in Bb minor.
Is it normal to "simplify" or compromise the key signature for some reason? How does one choose?

In this case, I believe the constancy of one key signature throughout makes it win out over swapping between key signatures every (subtle) mode change.

Note, in the chorus this particular song doesn't change the scale. It changes the key. From Bb minor to Eb minor (or maybe Gb major).

To clarify, the scale changes as well, but it's incorrect to say that it's Bb phrygian. It is Eb minor scale, even if it uses the same notes as Bb phrygian. The tonal center moves (or modulates) to Eb for the chorus.

The repeating "Alone" section moves upwards Bb - B - Db, making it definitively not Bb minor, and I interpreted this as Phrygian, but I guess it resolves to the earlier 4 part Eb - B - Gb - Db to an Ebm. Thanks for all the pointers and references, it seems this is not a simple topic at all.

I believe this is best answered in Key signature for writing in modes other than major and minor
and is by no means a straight forward simple answer.
